# Determining the CMRR of an instrumentation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, gain, cmrr

Design an instrumentation amplifier with the following specifications:
(i) 20 <  < 10^3
(ii) No resistor greater than 330 Ω to be used.
(iii) Minimum component spread.
(iv) Maximum input resistance
(v) Gain to vary linearly with resistance.
(vi) Given ideal opamps and resistors of 1% tolerance, determine the worst case CMRR
of your amplifier.
....could you answer the question?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You just pasted your homework assignment without asking a question about it.

Comment: Homework needs an attempt at solution and a specific question about where you're stuck.  Then you may get some hints, but we won't solve your homework problems for you.